# I am new in jmeter , how to create script for 1000 user in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am new in jmeter , how to create script for 1000 user in jmeter, i am trying record script in balze meter and import in jmeter but when i add it in to jmater it give me error 'emplty test plan see log file', please suggest me step by step how to create cript for log in(can i have to create 1000 user name and password manually). Also please suggest how to create user, username and password for 1000 user.

Comment: Look into jmeter documentation first.

Comment: This question is too broad, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to look what's in *jmeter.log* file? Normally it should contain enough information in order to determine the root cause of the problem.

Just in case here are some troubleshooting steps:

1. Update [BlazeMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium) to the latest version
2. Record your test plan once again and export it

   [image]
3. Install [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/install/Installation/) tool
4. Open terminal and type the following command:

   ```
   bzt "RECORD xxxxxxxx-Combined-JMeter-and-Selenium.yaml" -gui
   ```

   Replace `xxxxxxxx` with the actual file name part
5. That's it, JMeter GUI should open with your recorded script.